# Finding directory in another directory

Tags: c, directory

I need to find specific directory in a different directory, but for some reason my code finds directory in current directory but when I start to search for a specific named directory in parent directory, it can not find it there

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
void print_dir(char *dir_n, char *file)
{
DIR *dir = opendir(dir_n);

struct dirent *Dirent;
struct stat stats;

while(1)
{
    Dirent = readdir( dir );
    if (Dirent == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }

        stat( Dirent->d_name, &stats );
        if ( S_ISDIR( stats.st_mode ))
        {
            if(strcmp(file ,Dirent->d_name) == 0  &&  S_ISDIR( stats.st_mode ) )
            {
                printf("found\n");
                break;

            }
        }
}
closedir(dir);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  print_dir("..", "dirtest");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `stat` call to get if the "file" is a directory. The `dirent` structure have a member `d_type` which is `DT_DIR` for directories.

Comment: Have you tried `../` instead of `..` in the `print_dir` call? Don't know if this works, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @maditya no ../ won't work

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The `d_type` member [is not specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html), and on Linux, it's mainly available [only on BSD systems](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), and even then not all file systems support it.  It's much safer and more portable to just `stat` each directory entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return status of your system calls, and specifically `stat()`.

What's happening is that you read a name found in the `..` directory, but when you invoke `stat()`, you are doing so on `./name` and not `../name`.

This code should demonstrate the point:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void print_dir(char *dir_n, char *file)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(dir_n);

    if (dir == 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "error: opendir(\"%s\") failed (%d: %s)\n", dir_n, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }

    struct dirent *Dirent;

    while ((Dirent = readdir(dir)) != 0)
    {
        struct stat stats;
        if (stat(Dirent->d_name, &stats) < 0)
        {
            int errnum = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to stat(\"%s\") (%d: %s)\n", Dirent->d_name, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        }
        else if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp(file, Dirent->d_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("found directory %s (inode = %ld)\n", Dirent->d_name, (long)stats.st_ino);
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("found directory %s - not a match for %s\n", Dirent->d_name, file);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s is not a directory\n", Dirent->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_dir("..", "dirtest");
    return 0;
}
```

And this trivial variant should find the directory `../dirtest` if it exists:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void print_dir(char *dir_n, char *file)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(dir_n);

    if (dir == 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "error: opendir(\"%s\") failed (%d: %s)\n", dir_n, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }

    struct dirent *Dirent;

    while ((Dirent = readdir(dir)) != 0)
    {
        char fullname[1024];
        snprintf(fullname, sizeof(fullname), "%s/%s", dir_n, Dirent->d_name);
        struct stat stats;
        if (stat(fullname, &stats) < 0)
        {
            int errnum = errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to stat(\"%s\") (%d: %s)\n", fullname, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        }
        else if (S_ISDIR(stats.st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp(file, Dirent->d_name) == 0)
            {
                printf("found directory %s (%s) (inode = %ld)\n", Dirent->d_name, fullname, (long)stats.st_ino);
                break;
            }
            else
                printf("found directory %s - not a match for %s\n", fullname, file);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s is not a directory\n", fullname);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_dir("..", "dirtest");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my computer (and created directory ../dirtest for that), and it seems to work fine. Are you sure your directory is created and that you are searching at the right place?

Comment: yes I have several directories and it finds just one but not the others and I'm searching at the right place

Comment: What's the name of the directory that it does find?

Comment: it just directories that I created to test that function

Comment: COuld it be that you simply don't have the authorisation to search in the parent directory, and that it therefore fails?

Comment: Ok ... just wondered if there was something special about the name e.g. if it had a number and the others didn't

Comment: @Spam I have authorization to search in the parent directory

Comment: @maditya the ones that I creates are without any numbers and there is nothing special about them, just used mkdir

Comment: Don't think it will help, but I get a Segmentation fault when I don't find the directory, and you use this twice (second call is useless) : S_ISDIR( stats.st_mode )

Comment: I think it might help if you gave the content of the directory you are searching for, and the name of the file. Because I really don't see any problem on my computer and so I don't see what could go wrong on your side.

Comment: @Spam I know that the second call for S_ISDIR is useless is just didn't know what else to do and added it there. I have several directories directorytest, dirtest and testdir but I thought that there is something wrong with my code rather than directories